# How dose the computer know exactly the number of cylinder/head/sector of a hard disk?

Tags: operating-system, hard-drive

Supposed I have a hard disk, and all the data of the disk is set to 0x00, how dose the computer know exactly the number of cylinder/head/sector?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: I add an img file whose data is all set to 0 to the qemu vm by this "-hda xxx.img". And I try to read something from the img file by using the io port 0x1f0~0x1f7. but I don't know the number of cylinder or other vars above. e~, you know how to make this work?

Comment: As previously stated, this is not a programming question - you might want to try [su] ?

Comment: Because the hardware tells the computer?

Answer (score -1):

These days disks do logical I/O. The disk presents a linear sequence of blocks. If a block fails, the disk automatically assigns a new logical block to replace it. Disks have been doing this since the 1980's.